# Android: How to manipulate the sound of the whole device?

Tags: android, audio, root, android-sound

I'm trying to create a small equalizer-app for my android device, so I need to manipulate the sound of the whole device. Is this possible ? Or do the users of my app need root? Can I manipulate the sound of specific applications only?